# Visual studio 2010 database project data

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have Database project in my visual studio 2010 solution. When I deploy this database some data is also added in sql server in tables. I want to know where in database project that data is saved. I want to alter this data, so that when I click deploy in visual studio, new data is loaded in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi : I found the scripts under scripts\post deployment folder in database project. Thanks.